# Error in function when a class constructor called twice in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to create multiple search widgets using the "esri/search module". The second search constructor (for var geosearch) is showing an error that it is not part of function. Is it possible to use a class constructor again in JS?.  Please check the below script:

```
var map;
require([
"esri/map",
"esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
"esri/dijit/Search",
"dojo/on",
"dojo/dom",
"esri/dijit/editing/Editor",
"esri/toolbars/draw","esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
"esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
"esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "dojo/domReady!",
], 

function(Map, FeatureLayer, Search,dom, Editor, Draw,SimpleMarkerSymbol,SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol)
 {
 map = new Map("mapDiv", {
 basemap: "streets",
 center: [-56.049, 38.485],
 zoom: 3
 });

 var Search = new Search({
 allPlaceHolder: "Find by address",
 autoNavigate: false,
 autoSelect: false,
 enableHighlight: true,
 enableInfoWindow: true,
 enableSearchingAll: true,
 map:mapDiv,
 showInfoWindowOnSelect: true,
 zoomScale:1000
 },"Address"); });

 var geoSearch = new Search({
 allPlaceHolder: "Find by co-ordinates",
 autoNavigate: false,
 autoSelect: false,
 enableHighlight: true,
 enableInfoWindow: true,

 map:mapDiv,
 showInfoWindowOnSelect: true,
 zoomScale:1000
 },"Coordinates");});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is that you are using 'Search' for your own variable in the first call - which will overwrite the esri Search class.  The second call fails because of this.  Search is no longer the object you think it is.

Try using :

```
var mySearch = new Search({ ...
```

Beyond that, I don't what issues my arise by having two Search objects active.

Good Luck,  Bill B

Comment: I corrected the variable declaration. It works fine now. Thank you Bill.

Comment: please click this up as your answer then ... thanks, Bill